# Cannot see eclipse Run/Debug configurations as menus grow larger than screen height

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-jdt

Suddenly overnight something went bump and I cannot access the Run/Debug configurations.. in Eclipse because these menu items (including the scroll arrow!) have been bumped off the bottom of the screen:

[image]

I tried looking for a history limit, but that seems to have no effect:

[image]

Neither does restarting Eclipse. A new workspace might, alternatively any other good ideas - can I simulate moving to a new workspace by deleting some of its metadata? I can use keyboard arrow keys to get there, but it becomes tedious! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse stores the run/debug configurations in your workspace in directory `.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.debug.core/.launches`. Just delete some files `*.launch` there, and restart eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Runner](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/eclipse-runner#group-screenshots) eclipse plugin. You can browse your all launch configurations in the separate Eclipse Runner view.